# Truncate and re-number a column that corresponds to a specific id/group by using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, dataset

I have a dataset given as such in Python:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd


#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'runs': [6, 6, 6, 6, 6,6,7,8,9,10, 3, 3, 3,4,5,6, 5, 5,5, 5,5,6,7,8],
        'Children': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 120, 141,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141,123,15,85,36,58,89],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The above dataframe looks as such :

[image]

Here, for every 'id', I wish to truncate the columns where 'runs' are being repeated and make the numbering continuous in that id.

For example,

For id=1, truncate the 'runs' at 6 and re-number the dataset starting from 1.

For id=2, truncate the 'runs' at 3 and re-number the dataset starting from 1.

For id=3, truncate the 'runs' at 5 and re-number the dataset starting from 1.

The net result needs to look as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in python?

I wish to truncate and re-number a column that corresponds to a specific id/group by using Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a loop to go through each `id` and `run` cutoff value, and for each iteration of the loop, determine the new segment of your dataframe by the id and run values of the original dataframe, and append the new dataframe to your final dataframe.

```
df_truncated = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for id,run_cutoff in zip([1,2,3],[6,3,5]):
    df_chunk = df[(df['id'] == id) & (df['runs'] > run_cutoff)].copy()
    df_chunk['runs'] = range(1, len(df_chunk)+1)
    df_truncated = pd.concat([df_truncated, df_chunk])
```

Result:

```
   id runs Children Days
6   1    1      Yes  128
7   1    2      Yes   66
8   1    3      Yes  120
9   1    4       No  141
13  2    1      Yes  141
14  2    2      Yes   52
15  2    3      Yes   96
21  3    1      Yes   36
22  3    2      Yes   58
23  3    3       No   89
```

Comment: I was also wondering for a moment if OP wanted a filtering based on an explicit list, now I'm not sure.

Comment: @mozway i wasn't sure either which is why i didn't use a groupby but your method is definitely more performant!

Comment: Anyways, following your interpretation, it would be more efficient to `map` the thresholds from the IDs using a dictionary, then compare to the actual value for boolean indexing ;)

Answer (score 3):

Filter out the duplicates with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), then renumber with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
out = (df[~df.duplicated(subset=['id', 'runs'], keep=False)]
       .assign(runs=lambda d: d.groupby(['id']).cumcount().add(1))
       )
```

Output:

```
    id  runs Children  Days
6    1     1      Yes   128
7    1     2      Yes    66
8    1     3      Yes   120
9    1     4       No   141
13   2     1      Yes   141
14   2     2      Yes    52
15   2     3      Yes    96
21   3     1      Yes    36
22   3     2      Yes    58
23   3     3       No    89
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
        dd1=dd.drop_duplicates(subset='runs',keep=False)
        return dd1.assign(runs=dd1.runs.rank().astype(int))

df.groupby('id').apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out:

```
   id  runs Children  Days
0   1     1      Yes   128
1   1     2      Yes    66
2   1     3      Yes   120
3   1     4       No   141
4   2     1      Yes   141
5   2     2      Yes    52
6   2     3      Yes    96
7   3     1      Yes    36
8   3     2      Yes    58
9   3     3       No    89
```